# How to mock httpclient using mockery

Tags: unit-testing, go, mockery

I am trying to use Mockery to mock a Http client, but when I try to pass in the return value I get an error saying `type http.Response is not an expression`

Below is my interface and handler

```
type HTTPClient interface {
    Get(url string) (resp *http.Response, err error)
}

type Handler struct {
    httpClient   HTTPClient
}
```

Mockery generated a mock class which looks like the below

```
type HTTPClient struct {
    mock.Mock
}

// Get provides a mock function with given fields: url
func (_m *HTTPClient) Get(url string) (*http.Response, error) {
    ret := _m.Called(url)

    var r0 *http.Response
    if rf, ok := ret.Get(0).(func(string) *http.Response); ok {
        r0 = rf(url)
    } else {
        if ret.Get(0) != nil {
            r0 = ret.Get(0).(*http.Response)
        }
    }

    var r1 error
    if rf, ok := ret.Get(1).(func(string) error); ok {
        r1 = rf(url)
    } else {
        r1 = ret.Error(1)
    }

    return r0, r1
}
```

In my test, I am trying to mock the httpclient like below

```
httpClient := &mocks.HTTPClient{}
httpClient.On("Get", request.SubscribeURL).Return(resp*http.Response, nil)
```

I am not sure what parameters I am supposed to in Return. What should I be passing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `http.Response` (notice it is without square brackets, it denotes a type mostly) is an expression, while you should return actual response (a return value of the function), since a function returns two values `*http.Response` a pointer to http response struct and an `error` or `nil`.

```
body := ioutil.NopCloser(strings.NewReader("hello world"))
httpRespose := &http.Response{Body: body, Status: "200 OK", StatusCode: 200}

httpClient.On("Get", request.SubscribeURL)
.Return(
  httpRespose,      // http response with string in the body and the code 200
  nil,              // no error occured while response processed
)
```

Comment: ioutil.NopCloser is Deprecated as of Go 1.16, this function simply calls io.NopCloser.